# What is the largest taildragger in history?

Tags: aircraft-design, aviation-history, tail-dragger

Large, modern multi-engine airplanes do mostly have the 'tricycle' landing gear type. But it hasn't always be the norm. I remember at least one big plane with 'conventional landing gear', the German four-engined FW 200 'Condor'...

But, was it the largest of them all...?

Comment: How is largest defined? MTOW?

Comment: Possibly [Asiana 214](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asiana_Airlines_Flight_214). Granted, it wasn't supposed to be a tail dragger.

Comment: What is a taildragger/tricycle landing gear/conventional landing gear?

Answer (score 31):

If you are going by MTOW, I believe that would be the [Junkers Ju 390](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_Ju_390), which had a maximum takeoff weight of 75,500 kg.

[image: Ju 390]

Junkers Ju 390, By Bundesarchiv, Bild 141-0072 / CC-BY-SA 3.0, [CC BY-SA 3.0 de](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/de/deed.en), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=5418723)

Sadly, only a couple of these were built. If you are going by the wingspan, that would be the [Tupolev ANT-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_ANT-20) 'Maksim Gorki', which had a wingspan of 63m

[image: Maksim Gorki]

ANT-20, By Unknown - http://www.dkvnukovo.ru/photos/museum/photos/35.jpg, Public Domain, [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=3455646)

Comment: They could have fitted probably 8 more people in if they had put seats and windows in those awesome wheel nacelles.  Probably no trolley service though. Cattle class for sure.

Comment: @Wossname: Most modern planes have huge empty spaces in the fuselage, which is already pressured. Those nacelles are most certainly not pressurized! I believe that most aircraft carrying capacity limits are due to mass (weight), not volume.

Comment: @dotancohen, I have much to learn.

Comment: @Wossname: Then I'm in good company, and we're both in the right place!

Comment: I love that photo of the ANT-20!

Comment: That Art Deco fuselage on the ANT-20 is pretty slick

Comment: @TomMcW, "Air Deco"  :)

Comment: @dotancohen, You wouldn't see windows like those on a pressurized cabin.  Wikipedia says the service ceiling for the ANT-20 was 4500 meters---just a smidge higher than you're allowed to take passengers in present day U.S.A. without giving them supplemental oxygen.

Comment: @jameslarge: You're right, even the sharp corners on the "cupola" at the top indicates that the cabin is unpressurized. As mentioned to Wossname, I too have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 13):

I nominate the [Tupolev ANT-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_ANT-20), with a wing span of 63.00 m (206 ft 8¼ in), an empty weight of 28,500 kg (62,700 lb), and a MTOW of 53,000 kg (116,600 lb).

2 were built, first flight was 1934.

[image]
([tupolev.ru](http://www.tupolev.ru/en/aircrafts/ant-20_(maxim_gorky))) Note the two engines above the fuselage.

Answer (score 7):

I nominate the [XB-15 heavy bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_XB-15) prototype.

- Wing span 45.43 m
- Max. TO weight 32,139 kg

[image]

Comment: Better looking than mine :D

Comment: @ymb1 Yes but the production run of yours was 100% higher.

Comment: Oh c'mon Gorki looks great! :)